# Remove everything except what is in quotes java

Tags: java, string

I have:

```
String ex = "INSERT INTO `countries` VALUES (1, 'Afghanistan')";
```

How can I remove everything except what is in ' ' with java? What is inside quotes is variable.

Comment: please describe the problem you are having (this might help you formulate a better question), and as it is right now, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take pieces and parts out of the `String` by using the `substring`, `indexOf`, and `lastIndexOf` methods. You just may have to loop through a few times in case there is more than 1 pair of quotes found within the text. However, if it's just one, you could use this:

```
ex.substring(ex.indexOf("'"), ex.lastIndexOf("'"));
```

These will include the quotation marks. If you do not want the quotation marks, you would do:

```
ex.substring(ex.indexOf("'") + 1, ex.lastIndexOf("'") - 1);
```

Comment: Those `'`'s should be quoted.

Comment: Yes, Beau Grantham is right. With the quote it works! thank you

Comment: @BeauGrantham Oh, thank you for catching that for me.
And you're quite welcome Antony.

Comment: This will only work for one single quote pair.  Since you gave SQL as your example source data, and an insert statement in particular, you might want to consider the regex solution below, as it is a lot more robust.

Answer (score 1):

with regex..

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("'.*'").matcher("INSERT INTO `countries` VALUES (1, 'Afghanistan')");
if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

if there is more that one quoted word you could use a for...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Regular Expressions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
something like this maby...

```
pattern = "(?i)'(.+?)'";
String updated = EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(pattern, "$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into an array by " using String.split(")
Then the even index of the array is the string that you want